# Error: must return a plain object, instead received undefined

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, redux-thunk, geofire

My console output is producing the correct objects then crashing at the end of the array map and I can't figure out what's `undefined`. Here is my reducer, action, and list implement.

**reducer**:

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
      case LOCATION_FETCH_SUCCESS:
          return action.payload;
      case POSTS_FETCH_FAIL:
        return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**action creator**:

```
 export const locationFetch = () => {
   const geoFire = new GeoFire(firebase.database().ref('/geoLocations'));
  var keys = [];
  var snaps = [];
  return (dispatch) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          const currentLocation = [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude];
          const radius = 0.5;
          const geoQuery = geoFire.query({ center: currentLocation, radius });
        var onKeyEntered = geoQuery.on("key_entered", (key) => {
            keys.push(key);
            console.log(key);
          });
        var onKeyReady = geoQuery.on('ready', () => {

          keys.map((key) => {

            firebase.database().ref('/posts').child(key).
                  once('value').then((snapshot) => {

                    snaps.push(snapshot.val());
                  //  console.log(snaps);
                    dispatch({ type: LOCATION_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snaps });


               });//.catch(() => postsFetchFail(dispatch));

             });
        });
   });
};
};
```

**mapstatetoprops**:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {

var objectArray = _.values(state.posts)
objectArray = _.flatten(objectArray);
//console.log(objectArray);
  objectArray.map((post) => {
    const { dishname,
      restaurant,
      category,
      likesCount
      } = post;
      console.log({ dishname , restaurant });
    return { dishname, restaurant };
});
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {locationFetch})(DshdList);
```

The last output to the console and the error message I am getting are as follows:

```
10:43:33 PM
Object {
  "dishname": "shrimp bun",
  "restaurant": "momofuku ",
}
10:43:38 PM
▼mapStateToProps() in Connect(DshdList) must return a plain object. Instead received undefined
```

I do not get where this is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You must return object from **mapStateToProps** function, which you are missing. Place a return statement like below

> return objectArray.map(...);

Hope this will help.

Comment: I already mapped out the object array in the mapstatetoprops func. Do I need to do it again on post. Or do I need to return the mapping differently

Comment: See, you need to return an object from **mapStateToProps**, in your case it is missing. If you think that you have already processed the array, then just return it, it is up to your requirement. As there is no explicit return statement, undefined is being returned from **mapStateToProps** function.